# How to get SUM of columns and Group By unique ID's of rows in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

This is my current query i am using, but I am not getting the
   expected output.

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.email, SUM(ca.credits_added) as credits_added, SUM(cs.credits_spent) as credits_spent 
FROM weg_whitehound.users u
JOIN weg_whitehound.credits_added ca
ON u.user_id = ca.user_id
JOIN weg_whitehound.credits_spent cs
ON u.user_id = cs.user_id
GROUP BY ca.user_id
```

and my Original Database is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URRPo.png)

Comment: Post up proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 0):

You will get every possible combination of credits added and credits spent for each user due to the joins.

You probably need to join sub queries:-

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.email, ca.credits_added, cs.credits_spent
FROM weg_whitehound.users u
JOIN (SELECT user_id, SUM(credits_added) as credits_added FROM weg_whitehound.credits_added GROUP BY user_id) ca
ON u.user_id = ca.user_id
JOIN (SELECT user_id, SUM(credits_spent) as credits_added FROM weg_whitehound.credits_spent GROUP BY user_id) cs
ON u.user_id = cs.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.email
```